# FFmpeg transparent PNG black outline issue

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm encoding a video with a transparent PNG using ffmpeg. I noticed there's a slight black outline surrounding the image. Is there any way to remove it?

Output image:

[image]

Transparent PNG sample:
[image]

My ffmpeg command

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -ss 0.0 -t 8.5 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\6.mp4 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\text_and_emoji.png -filter_complex [0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS,scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#18ffff[0v];[1:v]scale=556.24744:141.41884[1v];[0v][1v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)' -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -g 75 -r 20 -preset ultrafast -strict experimental C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\test.mp4
```

**Latest edit:**

I tried using without `[1:v]scale=556.24744:141.41884[1v]`, the output still have the slight outline

Sample output:
[image]

Sample code:

```
ffmpeg -hide_banner -y -ss 0.0 -t 8.5 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\white.mp4 -i C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\text_and_emoji.png -filter_complex [0:v]scale=640:640:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=640:640:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2:color=#18ffff[0v];[0v][1:v]overlay=(W-w)/2-(W/2-325.33328):(H-h)/2-(H/2-567.7075):enable='between(t,0.0,8.5)' -ac 2 -ar 44100 -vcodec libx264 -preset ultrafast -strict experimental C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\test_movies\test.mp4
```

Comment: i removed the scale and output again, and it still has the black outline. If i removed all filter complex and left this

-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v] overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)'"

@mulvya what do you think? I noticed you answered few questions on ffmpeg

Comment: i attached screenshot and code in my main question thread there. It seems better than the 1st one, but still there's slight outline

Comment: Overlay scales output to yuv420p, which has subsampled chroma, which I think is the likely cause. Check with `overlay=25:25:enable='between(t,0,20)':format=yuv444` without the scale.

Comment: i tried and it goes like this https://youtu.be/Lq6usPTeWC0. Still can see the slight outline, but slightly better @Mulvya.

Comment: I notice if i put white color background, it will be fine. If i put cyan color, then it will show the outline. Any clue @Mulvya?